# How to tell what Normal Form my tables are in

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization, functional-dependencies

I have to find out what normal form my tables are in (BCNF, 3nf, 2nf, or 1nf). The problem is I am having a hard time being confident in my functional dependencies and keys being correct. Can anyone clarify how to figure out the functional dependencies and keys? Then I should be able to figure out what normal form my tables are in. I know 3nf cant have any transitive dependencies, and 2nf cant have any partial dependencies. I am a little confused on how to figure out if a table is in BCNF. Anyway thanks for the help in advance!!

Here are my tables....

```
Job(job_id, input, status, start_time, finish_time, PRIMARY KEY(job_id))

Error(job_id, errCode,description, PRIMARY KEY(errCode), FOREIGN KEY(job_id)    
REFERENCES Job(job_id))

tool1(database, evalue, job_id, PRIMARY KEY(job_id), FOREIGN KEY (job_id) 
REFERENCES Job(job_id))

tool2(specificity, job_id, PRIMARY KEY(job_id), FOREIGN KEY (job_id) 
REFERENCES Job(job_id))

Result(output, job_id, FOREIGN KEY(job_id) REFERENCES Job(job_id), 
PRIMARY KEY(job_id))
```

So from these tables I need to find the functional dependencies. I really dont know if its as simple as this?

```
job_id -> input, status, start_time, finish_time
errCode -> description
job_id -> database, evalue
job_id -> specificity
job_id -> output
```

If this is correct (Probably not correct) then the keys would be job_id & errCode right? I just need help figuring out if my keys and functional dependencies are correct!

Answer (score 2):

### Functional dependencies

By looking at the structure of the data (keys and constraints) we can formulate functional dependencies as a kind of **deducing game**. I tell you a value in one column (or in group of columns) and ask if you can say a value of another columns based on the values of the first columns. So if I tell you the `start_time` (let's say 8:00 AM) can you tell me the `job_id`? No, because different jobs might have started at the same time. So there is no functional dependency `start_time` -> `job_id`. The opposite direction is valid however: as there is only one `job_id` with any given value, you immediately know the `start_time` if you know the `job_id`.

There is at least one functional dependency you didn't mention: In relation `Error` as `errCode` is the primary key you can deduce the `job_id` from it. So `errCode` -> `job_id`

### Normal forms

**1st normal form**
No multiple values in one field so holds true.

**2nd normal form**
No key consisting of multiple attributes so holds true.

**3rd normal form/BCNF**
This one is impossible to deduce from the columns names only. Take for example the relation `tool1`. If I tell you the value in field `evalue` can you tell me the database? If so, then the dependency `evalue` -> `database` breaks the 3NF/BCNF.

Comment: no database and evalue are built in values you can change to modify the search. So they are built in values that the user selects. So they are independent of each other. But other then that do my functional dependencies look good? The errcode -> jobid makes sense because it is the primary key. I think I will have to change the error code table to have a primary key of errcode and jobid

Comment: Yep, they look good. only `errCode` -> `job_id` was missing (as `errCode` is primary key).

Comment: From data alone it is possible to verify that a given dependency does NOT apply; data alone cannot reliably determine what dependencies actually DO apply. Only knowledge of the database constraints and other business rules can find dependencies for you. +1

Comment: @sqlvogel good point. Although in theoretical context the data is sometimes used as a basis for functional dependencies (which might change as the data changes) it doesn't apply here. Removed first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies are *Business Rules*. When we say that a database design satisfies some Normal Form what we mean is that the database accurately implements a certain set of business rules expressed as dependencies. The rules have to come first though, and to be useful they have to be based on your knowledge of the world you want to model in the database and the requirements of the users of that model. A list of attribute names and even sample data isn't sufficient - understanding the requirements is what matters. So there is no magic formula for identifying dependencies. Once you have identified dependencies, it is relatively easy to devise a normalized database design (including keys) and verify that the design satisfies Normal Form with respect to those dependencies.